# How to set the default terminal window screen co-ordinates when Ctrl + Alt + T is pressed?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome-terminal

I would like my terminal to show up at a specific co-ordinates on my screen when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is pressed. Currently, terminal always shows up in the **top-left** corner. I have to drag each and every time to the middle of the screen. I'm using `12.04` and couldn't find any such options in the menu as far as I could see.

I read somewhere that something like `gnome-terminal --geometry="some co-ordinates here"` would bring this effect, but the instructions are for previous ubuntu versions that does not have `Unity` desktop.

So, how can I achieve this in `12.04` Unity desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Compiz features to achieve this. First install `compizconfig-settings-manager` package. Then launch the Manager, find "Place Windows" plugin (its icon is a blue arrow pointing down) and select second tab, which describes window placement rules. You can set the desired windows and their positions there, in the first field. For additional info take a look here: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place and here: http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching. You can get the exact window title with `xwininfo` (just mark the desired window with the cross and read the title after numeric Window id). Then create new entry, set the selection rule as `title=Window_name_from_the_previous_step`, set the desired X and Y position of the top left corner, activate the checkbox `Constrain workarea`. Should work.

Comment: where is this window placement plugin ?. this settings manager is like a maze. can this be done somewhere in a config file or something like that.

Comment: I do not use English interface, so my translation wasn't very precise. I updated my answer to make it more clear. If you haven't change your prompt in terminal your window selection rule will be someting like this: `your_name@your_hostname: ~`